# Windows scheduled Task - Stopping Console w/ error & Re-starting the service

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

How can I go by setting up a scheduled task that will cancel a java console that outputs a heap error and then start it up again?

I need to restart my wowza service because of some java heap allocating memory error that seems to happen every night.

I tried few options but could not get it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can find any number of tools to kill processes, like pskill from sysinternals/Microsoft.  Write a batch file that kills the process, waits until it's gone, then restarts it.  Once that's working, create a new scheduled task that runs it at a set time, making sure it fires after the heap error is certain to have occurred.  The trick will be to identify the process to kill.  Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an actual service, you can also do a

```
net stop <name of service>
```

or

```
net start <name of service>
```

PSkill is a great tool too.